# How can I get a JDBC4ResultSet from a PreparedStatement?

Tags: jdbc, resultset, minecraft, bungeecord

I'm coding a global bansystem for a Minecraftserver for Bungeecord (in Java). When a player, who is banned, tries to join, he should get kicked with the reason. I try to get the reason from a MySQL-table.

Here's the important Code:

```
PreparedStatement psn = null;
psn = Methoden.getConnection()
        .prepareStatement("SELECT Grund FROM BanList WHERE Name = '" + pn + "'");
if (psn != null) {
    ResultSet rsn = psn.executeQuery();
//  JDBC4ResultSet rsn = (JDBC4ResultSet) psn.executeQuery();
    if (rsn.next() == true) {
        ev.setCancelReason(
                "\2474[\2476Minepedia\2474]\n\247bDu wurdest aus folgendem Grund gebannt:\n\247c"
                        + rsn.toString()
                        + "\n\247bWenn du denkst, dass es ein Versehen war, dann schreib bitte eine Email an \247cminepedia@web.de\247b!");
        ev.setCancelled(true);
    }
}
```

It doesn't matter if I use ResultSet or JDBC4ResultSet, I always get `com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4ResultSet@65cda838`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Applying the `.toString()` method to a ResultSet object will return a string representation of the ResultSet object itself, not the *contents* of the ResultSet. In your case, the ResultSet object's string representation is "com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4ResultSet@65cda838".

You will want to use `rsn.getString(1)` or `rsn.getString("Grund")` to retrieve the *value* returned when you do `rsn.next()`.

By the way, you're using your PreparedStatement incorrectly as well. You should be doing

```
prepareStatement("SELECT Grund FROM BanList WHERE Name = ?);
```

followed by

```
psn.setString(1, pn);
```

before you  do the `.executeQuery()`.

Comment: Yeah, it is working, but after the reason there is a little "cr" or something like this. What is it and why is it there? Tank you :) EDIT: I managed it with substring, so it is working now :) Thank you very much!!!